# Unable to retrieve NSUserDefalts values after second launch of xamarin.iOS app C#

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, nsstring

I have an Xamain.iOS app where I'm setting my connection string and saving the current connection properties as:

```
public void SaveDefaults(){
var appDefaults = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(new object[]
    {
    new NSString(Language),
    new NSString(ServerName),
    new NSString(MBSFarmId),
    new NSString(Port),
    new NSString(MsgUrlSuffix),
    new NSString(Domain),
    new NSString(RepUrlSuffix),
    new NSString(RBSFarmId),
    new NSString(SupUserName),
    new NSString(SupPassword),
    new NSString(UserName),
    new NSString(UserPassword),
    IsReregisterEnable},
    new object[]
    {
      PersonalLanguage_Preference, ServerName_Preference, FarmId_Preference, ServerPort_Preference, MsgUrlSuffix_Preference, RepUrlSuffix_Preference, Domain_Preference, RBSFarmId_Preference, SupUserName_Preference, SupPassword_Preference, UserName_Preference, UserPassword_Preference, ReregisterDevice_preference
    });
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.RegisterDefaults(appDefaults);
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
}
```

and somewhere I was retrieving values like this:

```
var serverVal = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey(new NSString(ServerName_Preference));
var langVal = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey(new NSString(PersonalLanguage_Preference));
var reRegisterDeviceVal = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey(ReregisterDevice_preference);
```

but I'm not getting any previous value here. It's always showing (`null`). Can you please suggest any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**//Below Code perfectly worked in my project.**

//Set Value

```
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(UsernameTF.Text, "username");
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
```

//Get Value

```
string username = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("username");
```

Comment: PersonalLanguage_Preference is a constant string variable that holds some language..